# DH Key exchange attack: bad choice of g

Tags: diffie-hellman, key-exchange, dsa

In the group $\mathbb{F}_p^*$, Bob reads Alice's parameters as $p=234917$ and $g=281$ and uses a secret key $b < 400$ such that $h_b = g^b = 92646$.

Note that $p-1 = 2^2\cdot 11\cdot19\cdot281$

$281^{2\cdot11\cdot19\cdot281} \equiv 1 \mod 234917$

and that

$19452^{281} \equiv 1 \mod 234917$

Find $b$.

281 is too large for the Pohlig-Hellman attack by hand (which is how this question is supposed to be solved). I feel like the answer is staring me in the face but I cannot see it. Can anyone give a hint/help me? Basically we have $2\cdot(\text{order of g}) = p-1$...

Comment: '281 is too large for the Pohlig-Hellman attack': huh?   Recovering $b \bmod 281$ should take circa 35 modular multiplies, which is feasible for most adversaries.  Of course, with toy parameters like this, any choice of $g$ would fall to that attack...

Comment: Too large for Pohlig-Hellman attack by hand, which is how this question is supposed to be solved. Sorry for being unclear.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved the question by carrying out the Pohlig-Hellman attack for the smaller prime factors and finding that $b \equiv 3 \mod 11$ and $b \equiv 6 \mod 19$, then finding all the integers $< 400$ satisfying this and testing them. The answer is $b=234$.

I am still interested in if anyone has a solution which usesthe order of $g$ though.

Comment: Pohlig-Hellman does not help for a group of order 281, as 281 is prime. Instead you may want to consider using Baby-Step Giant-Step, which should take you about 35 modular multiplications as poncho mentions. This seems feasible by hand  (depending on time constraints). Having that said, I myself would follow your approach. In hindsight, an immediate solution to $b\equiv3\bmod{11}$ and $b\equiv6\bmod{19}$ is $b=25$. Thus we conclude $b\equiv25\bmod{11\cdot19}$ from which your answer follows.

Comment: Your solution *does* use the order of $g$, by using $11$ and $19$ as moduli. Using the Chinese Remainder Theorem, you get CurveEnthusiast's solution of $b = 25 \mod  209$. That leaves you with 2 values to check ($25$ and $25 + 209$) for modulus $281$, which is quite feasable by hand.